# Operaciones de suma y multiplicación para obtener un solo dato con MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando realizar las siguientes consultas anidadas SELECT en MySQL.
Si hago las consultas por separado funcionan correctamente, pero al anidarla en una tercera, el resultado que muestra es `NULL`.
Les comparto las consultas:

```
SELECT SUM(cola+colb+colc+cold) 
FROM fact
WHERE id = (SELECT SUM(cantidad*precio) 
            FROM detalle WHERE id_comprobante= (SELECT id 
                                                FROM fact 
                                                WHERE id = 17));
```

Comment: Claro, que un `id` coincida con una suma es harto complicado :) Repasa la consulta y pásanos el dataset con el resultado que esperas para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias @DavidJP, la idea sería la siguiente: Sumar los datos de una tabla (cola+col+b+colc+cold) y a su vez multiplicar y sumar otros datos de otra tabla (cantidad*precio), y mostrar ese valor como un total. Espero haberme explicado. Saludos.-

Comment: Te dejaron una respuesta, correcta, y deje otra respuesta con el query aggiornado... pero sin embargo, sigo sin encontrarle sentido, a lo que hiciste, y a lo que queres hacer.. falta informacion por ejemplo de relacion entre las tablas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comenta, intuyo que el OP tiene la típica estructura de facturas con varios conceptos:

```
CREATE TABLE fact(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cola float,
  colb float,
  colc float,
  cold float
  );
CREATE TABLE detalle(
  id_detalle int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_comprobante int,
  cantidad float,
  precio float,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_comprobante) REFERENCES fact(id)
  );
```

Al que le podemos dar estos datos de ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO fact (id, cola, colb, colc, cold) VALUES
  (17,1,2,3,4),
  (18,2,3,4,5);
INSERT INTO detalle (id_comprobante, cantidad, precio) VALUES
  (17,2,10),
  (17,3,20),
  (18,1,5);
```

En donde funcionan perfectamente sus consultas por separado, pero que intenta combinar más o menos así:

```
SELECT id,
  cola+colb+colc+cold subtotal_fact,
  subtotal_detalle,
  cola+colb+colc+cold+subtotal_detalle total
  FROM fact
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_comprobante,
      SUM(cantidad*precio) subtotal_detalle
      FROM detalle
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 ON id_comprobante=id;
```

Para obtener:

```
+----+---------------+------------------+-------+
| id | subtotal_fact | subtotal_detalle | total |
+----+---------------+------------------+-------+
| 17 |            10 |               80 |    90 |
| 18 |            14 |                5 |    19 |
+----+---------------+------------------+-------+
```

Si únicamente interesara la factura 17, sería:

```
SELECT id,
  cola+colb+colc+cold subtotal_fact,
  subtotal_detalle,
  cola+colb+colc+cold+subtotal_detalle total
  FROM fact
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_comprobante,
      SUM(cantidad*precio) subtotal_detalle
      FROM detalle
      WHERE id_comprobante=17
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 ON id_comprobante=id;
```

Sería interesante aclarar qué representan esos datos `cola`, `colb`, etc en la factura, ¿tasas fijas en la emisión de cada factura?

Comment: Gracias David asi lo pude hacer sin problemas. Los datos de cola, colb son impuestos que vienen detallados en las facturas, les puse ese nombre de ejemplo nomas, pero en mi tabla tienen su nombre correco como iva, iva21, iva105, iva 27 y asi todos los impuestos que se detallan. Saludos y Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esta sentencia anidada, donde la primer consulta tiene el indicador **s** (suma) y el segundo select **m** (multiplicación) como referencia, al final comprobamos con el id que sea **17** y corresponda a **id_comprobante** de la segunda tabla, ejemplo:

```
SELECT s.ID, (s.cola+s.colb+s.colc+s.cold) SUMA,
FROM fact s,(SELECT id_comprobante, (cantidad*precio)multiplicacion FROM detalle) m
WHERE s.id = 17 and s.id = m.id_comprobante;
```

Dime si te sirvió.

Comment: la respuesta esta bien, pero es mejor usar join explicitos... Esta forma de joinear ya quedo obsoleta. es mas, podrias usar una consulta con CTE (usar un with para la segunda tabla)

Comment: Gracias por las observaciones @gbianchi, me gustaría ver el ejemplo como lo mencionas ya que en general nos sirve como retroalimentación.

Comment: Ahi agregue otra respuesta. Sin embargo, chequeando la consulta de OP, la consulta esta mal de raiz... no tiene sentido y le falta informacion. por ejemplo, para que esta la tabla m aca, si no hace absolutamente nada en el select?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta dada por Antonio es correcta, pero no usa toda la potencialidad y claridad que podrías tener...

La misma consulta, pero usando join explicitos y CTE, quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
with 
    TablaMultiplicacion as 
        (SELECT id_comprobante, (cantidad*precio)multiplicacion FROM detalle)
SELECT s.ID, (s.cola+s.colb+s.colc+s.cold) SUMA, m.multiplicacion
FROM fact s inner join TablaMultiplicacion m on s.id = m.id_comprobante
WHERE s.id = 17
```

### NOTA

Esta consulta, no esta bien. Si la tabla comprobante tiene mas de un comprobante por cada factura, entonces va a traer múltiples veces la suma y una sola vez la multiplicación. Sin embargo, no queda claro en la pregunta la relación entre las tablas ni que datos se quieren obtener.

Comment: Excelente, esto da pauta a considerar varios tipos de solución, como mencionas, la falta de información y contexto propicia a que el enfoque de la solución no sea del todo correcto, pero queda en el autor de la pregunta adecuarla e investigar acerca del tema, aunque lo veo resuelto. Tomare tu ejemplo como retroalimentación, así seguimos aprendiendo, agradezco tu tiempo @gbianchi.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo y explicación. Pude conseguir lo que estaba buscando. Estoy aprendiendo a como formular bien la pregunta para evitar estos idas y vueltas y agradezco nuevamente a la comunidad por sus respuestas.

Comment: @JulianGabrielEspínola y cual era la respuesta a la pregunta que sigue teniendo problemas? como solucionamos tu problema que no esta bien planteado? imagina que otra persona llega a tu pregunta.. esta todo como incompleto, no?

Comment: Use la opcion que me dio David y me trae los datos tal cual figura en el ejemplo.

Comment: entonces, agradece que alguien adivino tu escenario, y de paso, acepta la respuesta que te sirvio... @JulianGabrielEspínola

Comment: Estoy en eso. No es necesaria tanta hostilidad. Te pido disculpas si no supe formular bien la pregunta, para proximas consultas voy a intentar ser mas específico. Que tengas un buen dia y no comentes mas si no vas a aportar nada. Saludos

Comment: @JulianGabrielEspínola No es hostilidad... hace mas de 2 dias, te dejamos comentarios respecto a tu pregunta... venir y decir lo resolvi, sin siquiera decirnos como, o que cosas nos faltaban, nos deja con la sensacion de que hicimos un trabajo que no sirvio... usar el boton editar, y agregar la informacion que faltaba no te costaba nada.. y aceptar la respuesta de David tampoco..